# Gulp, тестирование php-кода сайта без перезагрузки

Tags: php, gulp, gulp-watch

Допустим сайт расположен локально в openserver для тестирования в папке `C:\OpenServer\domains\site\`
Есть ли возможность, чтобы с помощью gulp при написании php-кода, изменения в браузере были видны без перезагрузки страницы?

**gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync').create(),
    replace = require('gulp-replace'),
    gulpif = require('gulp-if'),
    cache = require('gulp-cache'),
    del = require('del'),
    path = require('path');


gulp.task('serve',function () {
    browserSync.init({
        server: '/'
    });
    browserSync.watch('/**/*').on('change', browserSync.reload);
});


gulp.task('default',gulp.parallel('serve'));
```

этот код выдаёт ошибку `Cannot GET /`
`gulpfile.js` лежит в корне сайта

**----------P.S.----------** добавил код
**gulpfile.js**

```
var
    gulp = require('gulp'),
    bs = require('browser-sync').create();

gulp.task('serve',function () {
    bs.init({
        proxy: "test",
        port: 3000
    });
});
gulp.task('watch',function () {
    var watcher = gulp.watch('/*.php');
    return watcher.on('change', bs.reload);
});

gulp.task('default', gulp.series( 'serve', gulp.parallel('watch')));
```

допустим путь к тестовому домену `D:\OSPanel\domains\test`
в корне папки лежит файл index.php, но после правок ничего не меняется.
Подскажите плз, как правильно настроить?
т.е. сервер запускается под именем `http://localhost:3000/` и файл `index.php` работает, но после правок изменений не видно, страница не перезагружается

**P.S.**

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    bs = require('browser-sync').create();

gulp.task('serve',function () {
    bs.init({
        proxy: "http://test",
        port: 3000
    });
});
gulp.task('php',function () {
    return gulp.src('./*.php')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('/'))
});
gulp.task('watch',function () {
    var watcher = gulp.watch('./*.php', gulp.series('php'));
    return watcher.on('change', bs.reload);
});

gulp.task('default', gulp.parallel('watch', 'serve'));
```

выдаёт ошибку:

```
[15:00:39] 'php' errored after 96 ms
[15:00:39] Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'D:\'
```

пытался добавить такой код в `init`, но также не работает:

```
    bs.init({
        proxy: "http://test",
        files: ["**/*.php"],
        port: 3000
    });
```

Comment: реально ли такое сделать? может быть не обязательно с помощью gulp

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы bs работал в php и не выдавал

> Cannot GET /

требуется использовать опцию `proxy` c названием

1. сайта
2. вашей директории
3. алиаса в OpenServer

```js
const
  gulp = require('gulp'),
  uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
let
  bs = require('browser-sync').create();
gulp.task('js', () => {
  return gulp
      .src('./source/**/*.js')
      .pipe(uglify())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./build')
}); 
gulp.task('serve', () => {
  bs.init({
    proxy: "site.loc",
    port: 3000
  });
}); gulp.task('watch', () => {
  let watcher = gulp.watch('./source/**/*.js', gulp.parallel('js'));
  return watcher.on('change', (e) => {
    bs.reload();
  });
}); 
gulp.task('default', gulp.series('js', 'serve', gulp.parallel('watch'))));
```

Примерно так будет выглядить общий код.

Comment: посмотрите пож, добавил в вопрос код `gulpfile.js`

Comment: а какая задача выполняется в `gulp.watch('/*.php');` должна быть задача выполняющася при изменении php-файлов. По типу `gulp.src('./*.php').pipe(gulp.dest('./'));`

Comment: проверьте пож. что-то не работает код. добавил в вопрос код